# Can I use an old book on Objective-C and it still be valid today for building ios 7 apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I saw a tutorial on Objective-C (actually from a link on SO).  In that tutorial it used "by permission" code from a book from 2004, Sam's.  I started wondering if the language hadn't changed a lot so that if I found an old book, say at the Thrift store or used somewhere, it would be of value.

Would it be useful in learning to create ios apps?  I mean, don't I have to know the non-graphic things in Objective-C before I can do ios applications?  Isn't Objective-C still the *only* way to make ios apps unless you get a program that will generate code from your source in another language?

Comment: Pre-ARC books might seem confusing to you at the beginning but they are still very usefull. "Newcomers" (i don't mean this in any bad way) to iOS often think that memory management is a thing of the past. So yes, you can grab an old book and you won't waste your time doing it. Just keep in mind that some release/autorelease stuff is done "automatically" these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall
 this is the best place to learn objective c lecturer is Paul Hegarty in stanford University and he also work with Steave Jobs so that his understanding is much more better than any one else so i would like to suggest you that just learn from these lectrures these lectures include PDF of lecture

Comment: this is really great just try it once

Answer (score 3):

[Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) is Apple's Objective-C documentation. It is a 120+ page PDF, or broken down into sections on the web. This is a better starting point than a years-old book.

Answer (score 0):

I think no, you ned a new book, even in the years 2010 - 2013, 2004 is too old